# Custom display template for videos working for 1 of 4 videos

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, display-template

I've customized the Item-Video display template to surface data from some custom columns.  It's working perfectly on 1 of the videos, but not the other 3 that I uploaded.  They are all MP4's in the same Asset Library.  Why are the other 3 videos not displaying the custom template?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `path:https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/library` to test whether you could search these videos.

If you can't search them, try to request crawling by re-indexing your library.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/crawl-site-content